# UserDefaultでStringの配列を保存する方法について

Tags: swift, ios, swift3

Stringの配列をUserDefaultで保存し、再度読み込もうとしています。
ただ現在、読み込んだ際にnilになってしまいエラーでアプリが落ちてしまいます。

Playgroundでコードで試しているのですがどうやったらStringの配列で保存、読み込みができるか教えてください

```
import UIKit

let str = ["aaa","iii","uuu"]

let defauls = UserDefaults()

defauls.set(str, forKey: "str")

defauls.synchronize()

//ここがエラーになる
defauls.array(forKey: "str") as! [String]
```

Answer (score 1):

結論から言うと、メソッドの使い方は正しいのですが、「Playgroundでコードで試している」という試し方が間違っています。

**`UserDefaults`(Swift2までなら`NSUserDefaults`)が(PlatformをiOSとした)Playgroundでは動作しない** と言う事象はXcode7の時代に報告されているのですが、現在の最新版Xcode(8.2.1)でも存続しているようです。

[NSUserDefaults no longer saving values](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/15663#15663)

("UserDefaults Playground"で検索すれば他にも多数の記事が見つかります。)

---

`UserDefaults`の使い方を(iOSで)試すのであれば、簡単なSingle Viewプロジェクトを作ってみてください。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let strArr = ["aaa","iii","uuu"]

        let defauls = UserDefaults()

        defauls.set(strArr, forKey: "strArr")

        defauls.synchronize()

        //シミュレータ・実機ではエラーにならない
        print(defauls.array(forKey: "strArr") as! [String]) //->["aaa", "iii", "uuu"]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

文字列でもないものを`str`という名称の変数に入れるのは気持ちが悪いので`strArr`に変えてありますが、それ以外はあなたのコードと全く同じ内容です。

なお、上記のリンク先の記事にもありますが、このような使い方の場合、本当は`defauls.synchronize()`は不要です。

---

なお、`UserDefaults`からの値の取り出しは、様々な条件で`nil`になりうるわけですから、たとえ機能を試すためのお試しコードでも、`as!`のように「私のアプリをクラッシュさせて」型の演算子を使うのはお勧めできません。

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let defauls = UserDefaults()
    if let defArr = defauls.array(forKey: "strArr") as? [String] {
        //アプリの2回目以降の実行時(UserDefaultsに値を設定済みの時)はこちらが走る
        print(defArr) //->["aaa", "iii", "uuu"]
    } else {
        //アプリの初回実行時(UserDefaultsが空の時)はこちらが走る
        print("Setting new array to 'defArr'")
        let strArr = ["aaa","iii","uuu"]

        defauls.set(strArr, forKey: "strArr")
    }
}
```

条件バインディングなどを上手く使って「`nil`安全」なコーディングを(ちょっとしたお試しコードを書くときでも)心がけた方がいいでしょう。